# Update query not getting values correctly in nodejs

Tags: jquery, sql, node.js

I'm trying to deal with an update query in a nodejs server. It is correctly, but it doesn't get the values correctly, only the id, and I can't figure out how to solve it. Thanks a lot !

**Server-side:**

```
app.post('/update', function(req,res) {

    var data = req.body;
    var id = data.id;
    var json = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var object = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(object);
    var query = "UPDATE Control SET casate='"+ req.body.casate +"', reparate='"+ req.body.reparate +"' WHERE id=" + id;
    console.log(query);
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

**Client-side:**

```
function update()
            {
                var frm = $('#form');
                var data = frm.serializeArray();
                console.log(data);
                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/update',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success:function(data){                               
                        console.log("Update successfully!");

                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

**Query from console:**

```
UPDATE Control SET casate='undefined', reparate='undefined' WHERE id=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $.ajax you have

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

and then

```
data : {
    id: id
},
```

so the later is overwriting the first one

you can use this instead

```
    data : {
        id: id,
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
```

which means you have to change server side code accordingly

```
var id = req.body.id;
var data = req.body.data
```